# How can I validate the range A-K without I, using a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, validation

I need to validate a string which will have the format [char][char][num][num][char].

I need to find out if the [char] has anything between A-K but not I.

Comment: It needs to be done entirely in REGEX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [char class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and add the two ranges:

```
[A-HJ-K]
```

`J-K` is not really a range and adding the other requirements, try something like:

```
^[A-HJK]{2}\d{2}[A-HJK]$
```

[See it here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?380lb).

`^` is an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for the start of the string

`$` is the [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for the end of the string

Those anchors are important, otherwise you can match substrings.

Answer (score 1):

```
[a-hj-k]{2}\d{2}[a-hj-k]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KI3mOkLynBaWlkDL)